# Armature vanished, Alt-H not working, etc

Tags: armature, 3d-view, bones

I have a model rigged and animated but the armature is completely invisible and uninteractive. It still seems to be operating as the model animates normally and I can look at all the bone and armature properties but I can't select or interact with it in the 3D viewport.

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have pressed the [*Only Render*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/properties/panels.html#display-panel) button. Click it again to disable it and show all objects.

[image: only render]

> Displays only items that will be rendered. This option hides visualizations, overlays, the 3D cursor, and the grid floor. The 3D manipulator widget has to be toggled separately.
>
> This can be useful for a preview and for OpenGL viewport rendering.

Comment: Thanks so much! I wasn't aware that affected much more than the grid floor etc.